# Import a private API App (Azure App Service) as an API in a vnet deployed API management instance

Tags: azure-api-management

Has anyone tried to [Import an (private and not publicly accessible) API App as an API](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/api-management/import-api-app-as-api) when your API management instance is deployed in a vnet? This is different than just pointing to an ip address [like explained here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/api-management/api-management-using-with-vnet#connect-to-a-web-service-hosted-within-a-virtual-network), which no doubt will work.

However, directly pointing to an Azure resource, as the Import API App does, seems like the nicer approach. I wonder what the exact requirements are, as I've tried to import an API app that wasn't part of the same vnet, and it gave a DNS error after importing the API and trying it out in API Management (which only makes sense if it tried to call the API App as if it's hosted on the internet,  if the API App is accessible from the internet, there is no issue, that works perfectly).

There is a direct reference between an API resource and the API Management resource (it sets the [ResourceId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.apimanagement.servicemanagement.models.psapimanagementbackend.resourceid?view=azurerm-ps#Microsoft_Azure_Commands_ApiManagement_ServiceManagement_Models_PsApiManagementBackend_ResourceId) on your ApiManagementBackend). Also, I've set [HostNamesDisabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.websites.models.site.hostnamesdisabled?view=azure-dotnet) to `true` on the API App, which speficially claims that "the app is only accessible via API management process"... So Azure should handle the traffic between the two resources internally right (this is what i hoped)?

Trying to put both resources in the same vnet would be the next thing to try, but then i'd skip the whole Import API all together because then i can just point to the ip address. Which perhaps concludes that the Import API functionally is not beneficially in an API Management vnet scenario?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for me at the moment is to not put the API app in a vnet, and just disable access to the API app for all ip's except for the public endpoint of the API management instance.

After private endpoints become generally available for app services I might reevaluate this...